# Same column height with content inside

Tags: html, css

Today I am faced with a CSS problem. I had an issue where my two columns haven't the same height because of their contents and depending on the screen resolution . So I set the height of my columns to 650px .

Except now , according to the resolution , the button or content are out of the column (as the height of the latter is fixed).

[See here the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXHcx.png)

Ideas to solve my problem?

PS : I use Bootstrap .

```html
<article class="section-wrapper clearfix" id="rejoindre">
        <div class="content-wrapper clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <!-- Titre -->
                <h1 class="text-center">Vous aussi rejoignez l'aventure !</h1>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail" style="height : 650px;">
                        <img alt="..." src=
                        "assets/images/other_images/section_rejoindre/btn_decouverte.png">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3 class="text-center">NIMERIA Demo</h3>
                            <p class="text-center">Le Mode Découverte est un
                            module qui vous permet d'essayer sans candidature
                            une partie des ajouts exclusifs de Niméria.</p>
                            <ul class="pull-left">
                                <li>Sans candidature(sauf bêta)</li>
                                <li>Inscription rapide</li>
                                <li>Reset de la map</li>
                                <li>Accès au système de quête</li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <p class="text-center"><a class=
                            "btn btn-primary btn-lg" href=
                            "http://91.121.160.218/oldforum/forums/candidatures-postulez-pour-la-beta.193/"
                            style=
                            "border-radius: 5px; background:#597A78;">S'inscrire
                            et jouer !</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail" style="height : 650px;">
                        <img alt="..." src=
                        "assets/images/other_images/section_rejoindre/btn_world.png">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3 class="text-center">NIMERIA World</h3>
                            <p class="text-center">Niméria World est le serveur
                            original qui vous propose toutes les
                            fonctionnalités et ajouts inédits qui font le
                            succès du projet.</p>
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Sous candidature</li>
                                    <li>Création du personnage</li>
                                    <li>Choix d'une nation</li>
                                    <li>Présence des saisons</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <p class="text-center"><a class=
                            "btn btn-primary btn-lg" href=
                            "http://91.121.160.218/oldforum/" style=
                            "border-radius: 5px; background:#597A78;">Bientôt
                            disponible</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div></div><!-- .content-wrapper -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </article><!-- .section-wrapper -->
```

Comment: Do you have custom css (apart from the inline css for the height)?

Comment: You can use display: table and table cell.

Comment: Tim : No I don't have !

Comment: I tried table and cell but it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` to force all siblings of a container to have the same height.

[See this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oqt9mmog/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">Lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.box {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

In your case the `display:flex` should be used on the parent container for your boxes that should have the same height.

The Flexbox is [only partially supported in IE 10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and not supported in IE 9 and below. Please consider this if you expect to have a major part IE users.

Comment: In my case, which div is my container, because i tried "display:flex" evrywhere, but the problem is still here : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/42/1444898832-sans-titre.png

Comment: It should be your col-md-12 container. Don't forget to remove the height attribute! If you have no custom css you also shouldn't need the thumbnail div.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
body {
    background-color: #444;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
     width: 1005px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
#leftcolumn, #rightcolumn {
    border: 1px solid white;
    float: left;
    min-height: 450px;
    color: white;
}
#leftcolumn {
     width: 250px;
     background-color: #111;
}

#rightcolumn {
     width: 750px;
     background-color: #777;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/8weSA/2119/)

Comment: This does only work if the content does not span above your min-height. If it does, only the column with more gets more height instead of both.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i already tried the property "min-height" and it doesn't work :/